# Get Last Value of previous row partition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, lag

In my data set, each customer has some orders on different dates.
For each customer each month, I want to check his/her last order in the previous month in which city.

For example, it is my data for one of the customers.

| customer | year | month | day | order id | city id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1544 | 2022 | 2 | 6 | 413 | 9 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 2 | 17 | 39 | 10 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 3 | 5 | 115 | 21 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 5 | 29 | 2153 | 4 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 5 | 30 | 955 | 9 |

the result should be the same as this:

| customer | year | month | city of last order of prev month(prevCity) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1544 | 2022 | 2 | null or 9 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 3 | 10 |
| 1544 | 2022 | 5 | 21 |

(the first row of the above table is not my question now. )
I write my query using `last_value` the same as this:

```
select customer,
   year,
   month,
   last_value(City) over (partition by customer, year, month order by created_at desc
       ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as prevCity 
 from table1
```

but the result is false!

How can I correct this?

Comment: Not time to do the whole thing at the moment, but I think you need two levels of nesting: the first level to get a `last_value()` within the **current** month, and the 2nd level to use `lag()` to shift the results of the previous level by one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the window function `lag() over()` in concert with the `WITH TIES` clause

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       customer
      ,year
      ,month
      ,LastCityID = lag([city id],1) over (partition by customer order by year, month,day) 
 From YourTable
 order by row_number() over (partition by customer,year,month order by year, month,day)
```

**Or an Nudge More Perforamt**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,LastCityID = lag([city id],1) over (partition by customer order by year, month,day) 
      ,RN = row_number() over (partition by customer,year,month order by year, month,day) 
 From YourTable
)
Select customer
      ,year
      ,month
      ,LastCityID 
 From  cte
 Where RN =1
```

**Results**

```
customer    year    month   LastCityID
1544        2022    2       NULL
1544        2022    3       10
1544        2022    5       21
```